# Where can I download light pollution data?

Tags: photography, light-pollution

I'm creating a website with prediction of how good will be a night for astrophotography.
I take into account the Moon, clouds,  but of course I need light pollution data.

Where can I download a light pollution dataset or may be use some API?

Comment: there may be some helpful resources in answer(s) to [Why (actually) is the night sky so bright in the city? How far up is that happening?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/8795/6031) in Earth Science SE

Comment: https://www.lightpollutionmap.info/ might be a starting point

Comment: Thank you, I know most of those websites, bu still can find there only images, not raw data :(